# Android ActionBarSherlock change color of item when pressed

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I don't understand how to change the color of a pressed item in ActionBarSherlock. I'm overriding the theme `Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse` and when I'm looking in the source of this theme, I cannot find that blue color which my items have when they are pressed.
Can someone help  me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one style attribute responsible for the ActionButton background: **actionBarItemBackground**. Just set your own definded DrawableStateList as a value.

As an example, here is the default DrawableStateList:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/abs__list_selector_disabled_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:drawable="@drawable/abs__list_selector_disabled_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_focused="true"                                android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/abs__list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_focused="false"                               android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/abs__list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark" />
<item android:state_focused="true"                                                             android:drawable="@drawable/abs__list_focused_holo" />
<item                                                                                          android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in the ActionBar overflow. Perhaps you can also give a little insight into that?